# test cafe : removeRequestHook

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

So I use t.addRequestHooks to add a few requestMock

I have the impression that after the end on my test, the hook are still working.

Is there a way to remove all the requestMock in one line? or should I specify all the t.removeRequestHooks one by one?

Comment: I tried to reproduce this behavior, but didn't succeed.   In my test the request mock added in one test doesn't affect subsequent tests.  Could you share your  code reproducing the issue?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?